# Switching tabs in ConEmu with AHK

Tags: autohotkey, conemu

I'm trying to get ConEmu to switch tabs using custom shortcuts using AHK. ConEmu has two sets of shorts for next/previous tabs. They are `ctrl+tab`/`ctrl+shift+tab` and `win+q`/`win+shift+q`

I tried the following in AHK, but none of them work. In every case, either next or previous works, but the other direction seems to go to a random tab. I.e. I can cycle through the tabs in order with `alt+pageup` or `alt+pagedown`, but not the other:

```
!PgUp::Send ^+{Tab}
!PgDn::Send ^{Tab}
```

.

```
!PgUp::Send #+{Q}
!PgDn::Send #{Q}
```

Any idea how to get this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your AutoHotkey code.  Did you try and uncheck 'Recent' mode?

```
ConEmu > Settings > Main > Tab Bar > Recent Mode
```

That should make sure ConEmu goes in order instead of navigating back to the most recently active tabs.